# Как сортировать строку?

Tags: c++, строки, сортировка

подскажите как можно отсортировать слова по алфавиту в строке (`char words[255]`).Прошу прошения если вопрос глупый .

Comment: Поделите строку на слова (скажем, в массив), отсортируйте, соберите обратно в строку и выведите.

Comment: а покажите пожалуйста как это сделать ? я знаю где начало и конец слова.как их засунуть в массив ?

Answer (score 3):

если у вас `char words[255]` - это строка внутри которой содержатся слова, то надо

1. предварительно разбить строку на массив слов
2. отсортировать массив (например, с использованием стандартной функции `std::sort`)
3. собрать отсортированный массив в строку через разделитель

т.е. как-то так:

```
// разбить строку на слова
std::istringstream iss(str);
std::vector<std::string> words((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss)), std::istream_iterator<std::string>());

// отсортировать слова
std::sort(std::begin(words), std::end(words));

// собрать строку из слов
std::string result = std::accumulate(std::begin(words), std::end(words), std::string(), 
    [](const std::string& a, const std::string& b) -> std::string { 
        return a + " " + b; 
    } )
```

Comment: Объявление вектора можно сократить до `std::vector<std::string> words(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss), {});`.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, например, так:

```
char words[255] = "hsdvj sdfh euwru jcsjk afgfc fjk";

istringstream is(words);
vector<string> p;
for(string s; is >> s; ) p.push_back(s);
sort(p.begin(),p.end());

for (auto s : p) cout << s << " ";
```

Если позарез надо вернуть ту же строку - пересобираем ее:

```
words[0] = 0;
for (auto s : p)
    strcat(words, (s+" ").c_str());

cout << words;
```

Comment: Здравствуйте,возможно как то реализовать без векторов а через обычные массивы ?

Comment: Разбивайте строку на слова, создавайте массив слов, сортируйте, собирайте назад. Странно, что вас смущают вектора, а не `istringstream`...

Comment: `istringstream` тоже очень смутило ,пытаюсь разобраться но не могу понять как сделать массив слов,у меня есть индекс начала слова(первая буква) и индекс конца(пробел после слова) ,как мне это реализовать ?

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ: использование библиотеки algorithm:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string str = "hgnfasdsd";

  sort(begin(str), end(str));

  cout << str; //addfghnss

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: В задании нужно сортировать слова по алфавиту, а не буквы в слове.